# refresh a listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a list Box that contains the names of several files. I can select a file name and click delete. The file will then be removed from my rackspace account. How do I automatically refresh the listBox with out restarting my application?

I have tried the following

```
listBox.refresh()
listBox.Update()
```

and neither give me the result I'm looking for.

Comment: What is wrong with `ListBox.Items.Remove(item)` or `ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index)`?

Comment: Clear the items, then load it the same way you did initially.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this way and it seems to work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove items from a `ListBox` you have multiple options. You can reload the DataSource that you are using or you can simple remove them from the `Items` by using  `ListBox.Items.Remove(item)` or `ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index)`.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    // or 
    object item = listBox1.SelectedItem;
    listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Nice job on the code for working any other time, but if a datasource is set you will not achieve this.